# How to insert json data to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have some json data needs to insert to the mysql database.when i try this it did not store in the database as given values in json.what can be the issue?

Here is my code

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$records = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($records as $item) {
    $sql_data =("INSERT INTO data (day,amount,paid_by,friends) VALUES ('".$item['day']."', '".$item['amount']."', '".$item['paid_by']."', '".$item['friends']."')");
            mysqli_query($con, $sql_data);
        }
```

Comment: I guess you are a fan of SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, try to use [mysqli prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

The problem is in your loop, try to replace it by this:

```
foreach($records['data'] as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: now it inserts data to the table.but in friends column data stored as Array.how can i solve this

Comment: You can apply another json_encode to `$item['friends']` and store it as a json string

Comment: Or you can convert the friends array to string with coma separated Like this:
`join(',', $item['friends']);`

Comment: Note: `join` is an Alias of `implode()` ... so just use `implode()` ;)